# react native useState update

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have this :

```
const [debugStr, setDebugStr] = useState("This is a debug string")

function debug(str){
    setDebugStr(str+'\n\n'+debugStr)
}

function testPressed(){
    debug("Test1")
    debug("Test2")
}

// and later :
<Button onPress={() => { testPressed() }} title='Press me' />
<Text>{debugStr}</Text>
```

My problem is that only "Test2" is displayed.
I understand that useState is asynchronous and, therefore, it doesn't update the values on the fly. So, how can I do to be able to call twice a debug function like this one and display each string ?

Thanks.

Comment: `"I understand that useState returns a promise"`. No it doesn't. The updates are batched together because they happen in the same "tick" (for lack of a better word). You can add some delay between both the statements to display both the strings.

Comment: I wanted to say "is asynchronous". I corrected my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all the debug messages, you can modify your code to accumulate the debug messages and update the state once with the concatenated string. Here's a way to achieve this:

```
function debug(str){
    setDebugStr(prevDebugStr => str + '\n\n' + prevDebugStr);
}
```

Comment: Short and efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the function to display all debug messages like this;

```
function debug(str) {
    setDebugStr(debugString => ([
      str,
      '\n\n',
      debugString
    ]));
}
```